# How to load Spring Batch Job using JobLauncherTestUtils for tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, junit5

I want to test a job that I used to load as a SpringBootTest and SpringJunit4Runner. As I upgraded to JUnit 5 the jobLauncherTestUtils class no longer loads. The project is a Spring Batch application using Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE. My main configuration is called AppConfig and I have configured the step and job as beans that I can autowire in the test class. However, the application context which used to load now longer loads even. The error tells me the job is not added to the jobLauncherTestUtils.  I do not understand why the job can no longer be loaded when it could before. I'd appreciate some help in fixing this issue

src/main/com/indigo/search/config/AppConfig

```
    @Bean
    public Step orderIntakeStep() {
       return stepBuilderFactory.get("orderIntakeStep")
               .<Order, Order>chunk(30)
               .reader(orderReader())
               .processor(orderProcessor())
               .writer(orderWriter())
               .build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "orderIntakeJob")
    public Job orderIntakeJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("orderIntakeJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(orderIntakeStep())
            .end()
            .build();
     }
      ...
  }



   @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
   @SpringBatchTest
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
   class OrderIntakeJobTest {

       @Autowired
       private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

       @Autowired
       private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

       @Autowired
       private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

       @Autowired
       Job orderIntakeJob;
       ...

      @Before 
      public void initJob(){
         jobLauncherTestUtils.setLauncher(jobLauncher);
         jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
         jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
         jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(orderIntakeJob);
      j

   }
```

Comment: `The error tells me the job is not added to the jobLauncherTestUtils`: please post the stack trace of the error to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you shared, there is nothing that imports a configuration class that contains the job under test in `OrderIntakeJobTest`. You should have something like:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyJobConfiguration.class) // this is where the job under test is defined
class OrderIntakeJobTest {

   // ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you  Mahmoud, I really appreciate your help.  I did not have to load the configuration class in SpringBootTest and SpringJunit4Runner when I used the annotation @EnableAutoConfiguration so I don't know why I have to explicitly specify my Configuration class. Once again, thank you.